# some visual-studio 2008 questions

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have some visual-studio 2008 questions:

- Can VS2008 open VS2005 projects ?
- Is it possible to install VS2008 on mini laptop ? (intel atom, 2G DDR)
- if VS2008 isnt work, is it take any resource ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the question to be more readable, but the last one I have no idea about so I left it as written.

Comment: @tim: Since I've already hit the rep limit, I won't gain anything from answering the question unless he accepts my answer.  If I see that he doesn't accept any answers, I won't bother.  He seems to be improving, so I did answer.

Comment: Wow.  You spend the time to read a question, then spend the time to post a comment, but refuse to answer (an easy question) just because you won't get hitpoints?  SO has changed quite a lot...

Comment: @tim: Had I decided not to answer, I wouldn't have read the question.

Comment: It's about letting people know (in a friendly way) that they're encouraged to to give back to the community (in way of points) and to let answerers have a quick medium to decide if they feel their investment of time is worth it. But if you want to discuss this further I suggest we make a thread @ meta.stackoverflow.com, post a link here and take this discussion over there.

Comment: @tim: I can only hope that they accept my answer, as it was here, and I try to make my answer noticably superior to the other answers to increase the odds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding VS 2008 and MSSQL 2008 on a netbook - yes, works ok.
I have them running on an eee 1000he for when I have to travel.

No resource usage from VS when not running (just a lot of disk space), but remember to shut down MSSQL services when you don't need them - atoms don't like running a lot of background services.

Is a viable option if you have to move around a lot, especially if you have to fly economy (fits on tiny tray table with room for a drink too), but would not want to use it as an everyday working setup.

Comment: thanks, you help me alot with my internal conflict
of course i'll only use for small fix's in the code

Answer (score 3):

1. You should be able to open a VS2005 project in VS2008. It might ask you to convert it to .net 3.5
2. I would not see why you could not install it on a mini laptop.
3. I not sure what your asking.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, but it will convert it to the VS2008 project format, so you can't work on the same project in both versions at once.
2. Yes, assuming that it has enough disk space.  VS might run slowly, though.
3. No.  While it isn't running, VS will consume nothing but (a lot of) disk space.

Comment: OK thanks, do i nead to instal the sql server 2008 express during the VS2008 installation ? (i need the sql too, but is it will work on the mini ?)

Comment: I upgraded the RAM on my netbook and VS2008 Pro runs reasonably well..no slowdowns apart from the delay in adding references...am happy with it...

Answer (score 2):

1. Yeah, just went through the process myself. If asked to convert to .net 3.5 just answer "No" or "Yes", but take a backup if answering the latter.
2. Yes
3. No, no resources, except of hard disc space

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

1. Visual Studio 2008 can open 2005 projects, but you can't go back once you've converted it. If you want to go back, suggest you make a backup copy...
2. It should be possible, but the screen size may require a lot of auto-hiding.
3. Your question is unclear...please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on any computer with Windows as it's OS.
Vb 2008 will read files from Vb 2005.
If Vb isn't being used, it will not take up CPU or physical memory. If it is, simply use Window's 'Task Manager' to end it. While running many projects, VB does take up a lot of CPU and Memory.